# Google Cloud Storage stream aes encrypted video to iOS

Tags: swift, encryption, video-streaming, google-cloud-storage, aes

I'd like to stream a AES encrypted video file wich is stored on google cloud storage to a iOS device. One important point to mention here is that the decryption has to take place on the device.

Are some AES cyphers not suitable for that ?
Should I use some VM on the backend that handles the streaming part ?

Comment: It is not clear what are you struggling with exactly and what answer do you expect. Just for consideration - wouldn't https solve the encryption part? Would [streaming transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) or [media services](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/use-cases/live-streaming/) fit the needs?

Comment: Well the video is encrypted with a key known only by the end user. Thats why I don't need a secure channel. The video it self is already encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Secure Real-Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP), using TLS, providing a secure channel via ephermeral:ephemeral ECDH.

AES in a streaming mode is suitable too, should you be happy to manage symmetric keys separately. Suggest AES-GCM with 96-bit nonce. Remember to be aware of data limits of said counter mode. Additionally, remember the nonce, keypair tuple also have limits on usage, rotate the key appropriately (assuming random nonce per message).

Recommend libsodium bindings in Swift (SwiftSodium) for the above.

Comment: GCS doesn't support RTSP, so to do what's suggested here you'd have to implement a GCS-RTSP gateway, maybe on GCE or GAE.